# bash cat removes characters

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment, cat

I am trying to read an entire file into a variable without removing any characters.  I'm sure this has to be stupid simple.

This doesn't work, since it removes repeating spaces, all tabs and newlines:

```
$ echo 'fred               wilma' > somefile; z=$(cat somefile); echo $z
fred wilma
```

I can see the same filtering happening with simple assignment like this:

```
$ z='fred                 wilma'; echo $z
fred wilma
```

but not when I do this:

```
$ echo 'fred             wilma'
fred             wilma
```

How do I get a bash variable to stop being parsed and filtered upon assignment?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  Can you give some info on your bash install?

Comment: FYI, also checked, and it works the way you expect it to in zsh.

Comment: `z="fred        wilma"; echo "$z"`  seems to work ... however, getting `$(cat somefile)` to work is problematic

Comment: @gordon - does exactly as described in bash on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: echo "$z" instead of echo $z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `echo "$var"`:

```
$ z='fred                 wilma'
$ echo "$z"
fred                 wilma
```

Comment: ohhhh yeah.   I remember now that bash has 17 different levels of parsing parameters to commands and echo is a command.  If I haven't used bash for a couple months, it just mystifies me sometimes.

Comment: it's because it is interpreted as `echo fred            wilma`

Comment: (LOL, thank you stackoverflow...) it's because it is interpreted as `echo_fred____________wilma`

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
echo 'fred               wilma' > somefile; z=$(cat somefile); echo "$z"
```